# Trying to determine if there is any Advantage

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, plsql

If I was in SQL Server i would just look at the execution plan, but i don't have rights to do that in my Oracle systems and I cannot see any speed difference when running. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT c_ID, c_Date
      FROM Table1
      WHERE CUR_IND = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT c_ID, c_Date
      FROM Table1
      WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE('2015-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
      AND c_ID NOT IN (SELECT c_ID FROM Table1 WHERE CUR_IND = 'Y')
```

I guess my main question, which seems obvious sorta is, since Union is going to run a distinct on this query, is the Sub Query in the second select helpful? This returns about 400K records on the first select, and about 10K on the 2nd, with the sub query the 2nd only returns 2. With or without it I get the same result in what appears to be the same amount of time. (Wishing i could see execution plan)

Comment: Since you are selecting different columns in both your union'd queries (`c_Date` vs `CHG_DT`), I would think that removing the subquery is not guaranteed to give you the same results.

Comment: @sstan my mistake it should be the same... changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `UNION` at all.  Just have a single query with an `OR` between your conditions (unless the `c_ID`-`c_Date` combination is not unique, in which case `UNION` might have been filtering out duplicate rows as well. But I suspect this is not your case.):

```
SELECT c_ID, c_Date
FROM Table1
WHERE CUR_IND = 'Y'
OR LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE('2015-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Or... if the `UNION` from your original query was also performing `DISTINCT` duties for you, then simply add a `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_ID, c_Date
FROM Table1
WHERE CUR_IND = 'Y'
OR LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE('2015-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, it sounds like you'll be writing a query like this (adding in for completeness):

```
SELECT c_ID, c_Date
FROM (
    SELECT c_ID, c_Date,
           row_number() over (partition by c_ID
                              order by case when CUR_IND = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    FROM Table1
    WHERE CUR_IND = 'Y'
    OR LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE('2015-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
) WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Well that is the thing, with the subquery, I do not need to use the union to filter out duplicates, however, there would be duplicates if i used the Or as shown above. Every record can only have 1 Cur_IND = 'Y' however, some records do not have any 'Y', and those with a 'Y' could have other rows that are 'N' and in the date range.

Comment: Just add a `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause if you really need to.  But I don't see how using a `UNION` is appropriate in this case.

Comment: Well for example I could have a records, with ID = 1, c_Date 2015-07-05 and Cur_Ind = Y ... but the same ID, could have a c_Date 2015-07-15 Cur_ind = N ... so basically if there is a Y  ...come to think of it I can use your query and add a rank, to remove duplicates thanks so much for your help

Comment: In that case, what is your expected result?  only the `Id = 1, c_date = 2015-07-05 (Cur_Ind = Y)` record?  Because for that specific example, then adding or removing your subquery would change the results, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, i want the record with Y no matter what, there can only be 1 per ID, but for the IDs with no Y I only want a single records if one exists between those dates

Comment: I just noticed your `rank` comment (I missed that when I first read it). That does seem like a good idea.  Does that resolve your problem?

Comment: One final note: depending on what you mean by `rank`, just be careful with that, because it is possible for multiple records to be assigned the same rank, and could therefore cause you to return multiple rows for the same `c_ID`.  To guarantee a single record, you'll probably want to use `row_number` instead.  I mention that in case.

Comment: Right On thanks for the correction. Row_Number() is what I want.